# Showing Sub-categories on menu only if has products with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have simple query which populate menu with Main categories and sub-categories. This work perfectly

```
  // in controller
$cat=Categories::all(); 
View::share('categories_menu',$cat); 

 // in view
 @foreach($categories_menu as $category_menu)
    @if($category_menu->has('subcategories'))
         <ul class="nav nav-stacked cat-nav">
              <li>
                  <a href="#">{{ $category_menu['category_name'] }} </a>
                        @if($category_menu->subcategories->count())
                          <ul>
                            @foreach($category_menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
                              <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
                            @endforeach
                          </ul>
                        @endif
               </li>
            @else
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category_menu->category_name }}</span></a></li>
            @endif
        </ul>
@endforeach
```

This make output like

```
Main Category
   -Sub Cat
   -Sub Cat
Second main category
   -Sub in second main category
   ...
```

The problem is that it is loading also sub-categories which are empty. I don't want to show them and I tried to change the query with joining all three tables - `category`, `sub_categories`, `products`

This is the query so far

```
$cat = Categories::select('*', DB::raw('category.category_id AS category_id'))
    ->leftJoin('products', function($join) {
             $join->on('products.category_id', '=', 'category.category_id'); 
           })
    ->leftJoin('sub_category', function($secondjoin){
            $secondjoin->on('sub_category.category_id', '=', 'category.category_id');
           })
    ->whereNotNull('products.sub_cat_id')
    ->get();
```

The result is strange ( image )
[image]

It's should show me only two main categories each with one sub. On the image you can see my product table

```
Category 1
  -sub1
Category 2
  -sub3
```

[image]

If need some more source or something i can provide.

Update with models:

Categories model

```
class Categories extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');

    } 
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SubCategories', 'category_id');
    } 
}
```

SubCategories model

```
class SubCategories extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'sub_category';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sub_cat_id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('Product', 'sub_cat_id');
    } 
}
```

Products model

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Categories', 'category_id');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: You should look at Eloquant relationships you will save a lot of effort

Comment: I have them already.. sort of.. I have made relations between tables in my Models.,.

Comment: Can you add them in your main post? It will be easier that doing a huge query

Comment: I've added them to the question. Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @foreach($categories_menu as $category_menu)
    @if($category_menu->has('subcategories'))
         <ul class="nav nav-stacked cat-nav">
              <li>
                  <a href="#">{{ $category_menu['category_name'] }} </a>
                        @if($category_menu->subcategories->count())
                          <ul>
                            @foreach($category_menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
                              @if($subcategory->products->count())
                                 <li class=""><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
                              @endif
                            @endforeach
                          </ul>
                        @endif
               </li>
            @else
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $category_menu->category_name }}</span></a></li>
            @endif
        </ul>
@endforeach
```

I added a condition for subcatergy to be displayed only if their products count is above 0.

Comment: Thank's. But with which query? Because I get same result as the image but sub-categories are there once not twice like on the image

Comment: Ahh got it. With initial query `$cat=Categories::all();`

Comment: Yes with the initial query

Comment: So simple...Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, relationship are really easy